# Is there an "algorithm" or a general formula to find sums for given sequences, for example $30+42+56+72+\ldots +10100$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there an "algorithm" or a general formula to find sums for given sequences $x_0 + x_1 + \ldots + x_n$ with $0\leq i\leq n$ and $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$? I always have a hard time figuring out the right summation.
For example if we have $30+42+56+72+ \ldots +10100$. How would I find a correct sum for it?

EDIT: *My solution thanks to JMovaritz which I commented on his answer*:

> Thank you. I wasn't entirely lazy either:
>
> $$\begin{align}a+b+c=&&\color{red}{30}&\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{12}}42\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{14}}56\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{16}}72+90+\ldots\\3a+b=&&&\phantom{0}\color{red}{12}\qquad 14\qquad 16\\2a=&&&\,\,\!\qquad \color{red}{2}\qquad
>  \;\,\,2\end{align}$$ Thats why we need to solve
> $$\begin{cases}2a=2\\3a+b=12\\a+b+c=30\end{cases}$$ which yields
> $a=1,b=9$ and $c=20$ and therefore $u_n=n^2+9n+20$ and
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{96} n^2+9n+20.$$

Comment: To have any hope of finding such a sum you need to make it absolutely clear what pattern the terms in the sum follow.  You write $30+42+56+72+\dots+10100$... but without more context who is to say that within the dots you don't have $30+42+56+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+\dots+10100$ instead of whatever you were thinking of.

Comment: Once you *do* make it clear, for example if it were the case that your terms follow the pattern of being the $i$'th term given by $a_i = i^2+11i+30$, then you can just split the sum and use what you know of the sums $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 1, \sum\limits_{i=0}^n i$ and $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for the ambiguity. I indeed meant this sequence. Could you explain to me how you came to the representation of the $i$-th term?

Comment: Difference of difference of terms happened to be constant (*for those terms listed so far*).  This is a "standard" type of sequence which is taught at an elementary level, just after arithmetic sequences and geometric sequences.  https://www.radfordmathematics.com/algebra/sequences-series/difference-method-sequences/quadratic-sequences.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I understood that. But that doesn't work for more complex sequences, right? What about a general sequence that has mixed parts in it where you can't apply these methods of the link you provided?

Comment: The techniques will depend entirely on what the exact sequence of summands is.  A fully generalized technique or method doesn't exist or would be too complicated to be useful.  We can tell you what to do for certain special sequences which follow some certain "nice" forms... especially for those sequences you are most commonly going to encounter when first being introduced to the topic.  In some of the more exotic questions, there will not be any simplification that can be made.  The best you can do for now is to try to decompose your sequences into smaller terms of known forms.

Comment: This is analogous to the same kind of question for definite integrals. There is **no** general algorithm.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! It's been a while since I heard anything about this in school/university. Unfortunately there in school was only "scratching on the surface" and I was annoyed that I could not solve this one school task myself.

Comment: I would add that if the sequence terms are defined as polynomials of n to the power of k, than the sum polynomial will be a power of k+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering comments, one can *guess* that your sequence is going to be one of the common sequence types, e.g. arithmetic, geometric, or quadratic, etc...  We can have an idea of which this is by looking at the common differences, the common ratios, or the common differences of common differences, etc...

In your case, we can guess then that the sequence is indeed quadratic since the common difference of common differences is in fact the same for all listed terms.

(*N.B. This is a guess.  Any formal scenario should have been very explicitly clear what pattern the terms follow.  Without such an explicit definition of what pattern the terms follow any such guess would only be a guess and there is no guarantee that the unlisted terms follow the same pattern, making the problem impossible and underspecified*)

Continuing to operate under the assumption that the summands follow a quadratic sequence, we can use standard techniques to learn that the terms in the sequence are given by $a_i = i^2+11i+30$ for $0\leq i\leq 95$ and so your sum which was informally written as $30+42+56+\dots+10100$ is formally written as:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{95}\left(i^2+11i+30\right)$$

This can be split apart by linearity of summation then as:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{95}\left(i^2\right)+11\sum\limits_{i=0}^{95}\left(i\right)+30\sum\limits_{i=0}^{95}\left(1\right)$$

Now, each of these three sums are of what should be known forms to you.  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 1 = (n+1)$, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Replacing these expressions in and replacing the value of $n$ into the above and completing the algebraic simplifications will lead you to a final answer of $343360$

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't entirely lazy either:

$$\begin{align}a+b+c=&&\color{red}{30}&\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{12}}42\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{14}}56\underbrace{+}_{\phantom{16}}72+90+\ldots\\3a+b=&&&\phantom{0}\color{red}{12}\qquad 14\qquad 16\\2a=&&&\,\,\!\qquad \color{red}{2}\qquad \;\,\,2\end{align}$$ Thats why we need to solve $$\begin{cases}2a=2\\3a+b=12\\a+b+c=30\end{cases}$$ which yields $a=1,b=9$ and $c=20$ and therefore $u_n=n^2+9n+20$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{96} n^2+9n+20.$$

Comment: Careful of off-by-one errors.  If you treat the leading term in the sequence as the zero'th term or if you treat it as the first term.

Comment: Oh, yeah. It's 1 to 96, right?

Answer (score 2):

Write out:

$$30, 30 + 12, 30 + 12 + 14, 30 + 12 + 14 + 16, \ldots$$

How many $30$s do you have?  How many $12$s? ....

Comment: The number 30 appears in all subsums. 12, however, appears in all subsums -1. Does this mean, that 30 is a constant factor?

Comment: This leads to $30\cdot 96 + 12\cdot 95 + 14\cdot 94 + 16\cdot 83 +\dots + \square \cdot 3 + \square \cdot 2 + \square \cdot 1$.  I for one don't find that much easier to calculate than the original sequence.

Comment: I've understood how you can find the $i$-th term of this quadratic sequence now. But what should I do when I can't apply the formular for quadratic/linear sequences because the sequence has mixed operations (e.g. is more complex)?